# Agregar contenido a ArrayList static

Tags: java

estoy aprendiendo a programar en Java, y tengo una duda, se puede agregar contenido a un public static Arraylist desde otro paquete del programa?

Por ejemplo asi:

```
package paquete1;
public class clase1{
      public static ArrayList<Vehiculo>  Vehiculos;
 public void addVehiculo(Vehiculo Vehiculo){}
}
```

y en otra clase y paquete:

```
package paquete2;
import paquete1
public class clase2{
Vehiculo carro;
paquete1.Vehiculos.addVehiculo(carro);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí se puede, si quieres usar el método `addVehiculos` sería algo como esto

```
package paquete1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Clase1 {
 private static ArrayList<Vehiculo>  vehiculos = new ArrayList(); // debes inicializar el arraylist
 public static void addVehiculo(Vehiculo vehiculo) {
   vehiculos.add(vehiculo); // el metodo add es propio de ArrayList y sirve para agregar elementos.
 }
}
```

En tu otra clase sería:

```
package paquete2;
import paquete1.Clase1;
import paquete1.Vehiculo;
public class Clase2 {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Clase1.addVehiculo(new Vehiculo()); // La clase1 debe tener un método estatico que se llama addVehiculo.
    System.out.println("se agregó un Vehiculo");
  }
}
```

[Aquí](https://repl.it/repls/DelightfulFreshAgents) te dejo un enlace donde funciona el código que te he sugerido.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Amigo, me sirvió mucho.

Comment: Genial, si te sirvió no olvides votar mi respuesta y/o aceptarla.